# Which copy will be used when RAID1 loses a piece of data?

Tags: windows-7, raid-1, hard-drive-failure

The case of complete drive failure is pretty clear for RAID1: the faulty drive simply does not work and data is being read from the good one.

Now the other real situation: the drive works, but some of it's data becomes slightly, uh ... different from the original data due to some local magnetic surface failure or SSD cell failure. One drive in RAID1 contains real data, other contains corrupted data.

How Windows 7 software RAID1 detects which copy to use?

Comment: Also: [How does RAID 1 determine whether a disk is corrupted?](http://superuser.com/questions/389093/how-does-raid-1-determine-whether-a-disk-is-corrupted)

Comment: I would think Windows would mark the drive as offline somewhere.

Comment: This is Windows software raid with no controller so that question does not really answer it.